# .gitlab-ci.yml - control which java version is used

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml file for my project

```
image: maven:3-jdk-7

build:
  script: "mvn install -B"
```

Which starts with the following output

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.0.4 (014aa8c)
WARNING: image is not supported by selected executor and shell
Using Shell executor...
Running on pauloconnell-HP-ZBook-15...
Fetching changes...
....
HEAD is now at 95ddd4f maven settings
....
   c8a639e..d881b78  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 95ddd4fc as master...
HEAD is now at 95ddd4f... maven settings
$ mvn install -B
```

but then fails with error where java 8 is being used for the build

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.260s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 04 18:55:47 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 77M/967M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:apt-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-5:process (default) on project om-interface-eircom: Unable to locate the apt compiler in:
[ERROR] /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/../lib/tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.5 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.apt.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

I do have java 8 installed locally but I expected the docker image definition to control this.

Can anybody suggest how i can work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recommend step to docker runner instead of shell and then replace "image: maven:3-jdk-7" by image which have java 8? For example:

```
image: openjdk
```

As you use maven and do not install it, may be you need its image instead:

```
image: maven
```

Answer (score 1):

Having done some digging today, the first warning was key

```
WARNING: image is not supported by selected executor and shell
```

indicating that I was attempting to execute a 'docker' 'image' via a 'shell' runner. I edited the file

```
/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
```

from

```
/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
name = "runner"
url = "http://10.139.11.103:8987/ci"
token = "xxxx"
tls-ca-file = ""
executor = "shell"
[runners.ssh]
[runners.docker]
  image = ""
  privileged = false
[runners.parallels]
  base_name = ""
[runners.virtualbox]
  base_name = ""
```

dropping all the docker and other runner settings, and added an 'environment' tag

```
concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
  name = "runner"
  url = "http://10.139.11.103:8987/ci"
  token = "xxxx"
  tls-ca-file = ""
  executor = "shell"
  shell="bash"
  environment= ["JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/"]
```

The final task was to updated by '.gitlab-ci.yml' file to

```
maven-package:
  script: "mvn install -B"
```

which calls the 'maven-package' module.